# sudo dnf module list |grep -I nginx

Tags: dnf

Below is result of  `sudo dnf module list |grep -I nginx` on RHEL8.8, doe it mean
there are already 5 different nginx servers (1.14, 1,16 , 1.18, 1.20, 1.22) installed  ?

Any hints are more than welcome!

```
nginx                1.14 [d][e]     common [d]                                nginx webserver                                                                                               
nginx                1.16            common [d]                                nginx webserver                                                                                               
nginx                1.18            common [d]                                nginx webserver                                                                                               
nginx                1.20            common [d]                                nginx webserver                                                                                               
nginx                1.22            common [d]                                nginx webserver
```

Answer (score 1):

`dnf module list` lists all available modules, so this only means there are 5 versions of nginx available. To list modules that are enabled (meaning you can install packages from it) use

```
dnf module list --enabled
```

or to list installed modules

```
dnf module list --installed
```

you can also see which module is enabled or installed from the default list of all modules:

```
[d]efault, [e]nabled, [x]disabled, [i]nstalled
```

so in your case the `1.14` version (or stream in modularity terminology) is enabled, but not installed.

See the [Fedora Modularity documentation](https://docs.fedoraproject.org/en-US/modularity/using-modules/) for more details (I find the Fedora documentation easier to understand, it works the same in Fedora and RHEL).